# How to delete a panel in the classic desktop?

Tags: gnome, panel

I'm using 12.04 beta 2. I installed the classic desktop and I'm using the AWN dock. I tried right clicking on the bottom panel to delete it like you used to do in earlier versions, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 33):

[image]

The *secret* key combination with the panels in Oneiric is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> + Right Click

The *Super* key is also known as the *Win* or *Windows* key.

If you are using Precise (12.04) then for me the same key combination is required.

However, as reported by @tachyons and @dobey the simpler <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Click is required.

N.B. if you are using Gnome-Classic (No Effects) OR for whatever reason compiz is not running then the key combination automatically defaults to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Click

In fact - its the same key combination for any gnome-panel changes such as adding or moving panel applets.