# How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)?

Tags: system-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu server on my machine, is there a step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish that or a guide that will just go through the basic steps of installing Ubuntu Server from beginning to end.

<sup>Instructions originally for 13.04.</sup>

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First, you will need to download the current version of [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). A 64 bit version is recommended, but you can also download a 32bit version from http://releases.ubuntu.com/.  Once downloaded you need to create a bootable CD/DVD or USB flash.

- [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Once done, put the disc in your drive, or insert the USB flash, and reboot your machine. Make sure that you set your BIOS to boot either from the CD/DVD or USB flash depending on which installation method you choose.

Once booted, just follow the steps shown in the images below.

---

1. On the first screen you can choose you language of install.

   [image]
2. Select Install Ubuntu Server.

   [image]
3. Select the language used for the installation process.

   [image]
4. Select your geographical location.

   [image]
5. Configure your keyboard.  I choose no to manually choose the keyboard.

   [image]
6. I choose the English (US) for country origin.

   [image]
7. I choose the English (US) keyboard layout.

   [image]
8. At this point the system will detect the hardware to find a CD-ROM drive.

   [image]
9. At this step, the installation will detect and load any additional component.

   [image]
10. At this step, the installation will detect the network hardware.

    [image]
11. Type in the host name you want to configure your server as.

    [image]
12. Type in the user's name.

    [image]
13. Type in a password for the username.

    [image]
14. Choose whether to encrypt your home directory or not.  I recommend selecting No I recommend selecting No because it makes it easier to do recovery if needed in case a corruption of data happens.

    [image]
15. Configure clock, and time zone.

    [image]
16. At this point, the installation is detecting disks, and other hardware.

    [image]
17. At this stage is were you partition your disk(s).  Select Guided as it is the default method.

    [image]
18. Select the partition of your choice, is this installation its the SCSI1.

    [image]
19. Select Yes to start writing the changes to disks, and configure LVM.

    [image]
20. Answer Yes to actually write the changes to disk.

    [image]
21. The installation is copying data at this stage.

    [image]
22. At this stage the installation is configuring Apt Sources.List.

    [image]
23. This is were you can configure a Proxy.  I select Continue since I'm not using a proxy.

    [image]
24. The installation is selecting the software being installed.

    [image]
25. This is where you configure how to install updates.  I choose the automatic method.

    [image]
26. You can choose one these option at the time of install or later.  if you select continue, you can manually choose what you want to install later.

    [image]
27. Cleaning up is being done.

    [image]
28. Starting the installation of Grub

    [image]
29. Select Yes to install grub to the Master Boot Record.

    [image]
30. Finishing the installation.  Select continue and remove the disk or USB.

    [image]

You're done.  Reboot your machine, and type in your username you created earlier, and your password to login.  That is it, you are now logged in to your new Ubuntu server!

Comment: Wow, great answer. How did you get the screenshots?

Comment: @Seth OMG! virtualbox, vmware, qemu, KMV, you pick one ;)

Comment: @Braiam Man... I didn't even think of those... duh.

Comment: @Seth I used VirtualBox.

Comment: This installed GRUB on the host machine. The host machine now tries to boot from the USB drive, and when it isn't in, boots to GRUB command line. It would be helpful to explain how to avoid messing up the host system's bootloader.

Answer (score -1):

Some more details about the other options in the first Step.

First, this menu also offers you an option to **Check disc for defects**. Although I'm sure you've done well in creating your media, all it takes is for a small
corruption in the download or with the dd command and you would end up
with invalid media. This is extremely rare—but it does happen from time to
time. If you have the extra time, it may make sense to verify your media.

This menu gives you the option to **Test memory**. This is an option
I've found myself using far more often than I'd like to admit. Defective
RAM on computers and servers is surprisingly common and can cause all
kinds of strange things to happen. For one, defective RAM may cause your
installation to fail. Worse, your installation could also succeed—and I say
that's worse due to the fact you'd find out about problems later rather than
right away. While doing a memory test can add considerable time to the
installation process, I definitely recommend it, especially if the hardware is
new and hasn't ever been tested at all. In fact, I make it a process to test the
RAM of all my servers once or twice a year, so this media can be used as a
memory tester any time you need one.

**The Rescue a broken system**The Rescue a broken system option is
also useful to recover systems that, for some reason, are unable to boot at all.

Source - Mastering Ubuntu Server(book)