# How do I install Ubuntu Server 12.04 without losing my Windows 7 files?

Tags: server, dual-boot, partitioning

I have 3 partitions on my Compaq Presario CQ 57 in which:

- Partition 1 has 55 GB (it has Windows 7).
- Partition 2 has 225 GB with no data stored
- Partition 3 has 18GB free.

So, I want to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 in partition of #3 but I don't know how to make it and I don't want to lose my windows 7 files.

Please help me.

Comment: What do mean by 'make it'? Also, does the 18GB partition have *any* files on it? Please edit your question to include that, that'll help us a lot.

Comment: Just one question... why are you using the servers installation? Also, have you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-13-04-step-by-step ?

Comment: Though, one note, do *not* select the `Guided - Use entire disk`, `Guided - Use entire disk and set up LVM`, or `Guided - Use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM` options, because this will use the *entire* disk (like it says) and will write over all of your partitions. Use the `Manual` Option and look up (Google, Manual for Ubuntu Server, etc.) how to select a specific partition to install to. Best of Luck!

Answer (score 2):

First Step: Make a secondary hdd part with windows. Use Disk Manager. And least give 25 gb for ubuntu.

Second step: Take note what size of hdd part. it is important.

Third step: Plug Usb or install data. and select install button. after language step you will see install part step. stop.

fourth step: select something else. and find your hdd part by size. only delete it. and create two part .

1. part: ubuntu system /ext4 /20 gb.
2. part: swap swap/5gb

fiveth step: confirm it. and do other steps. after installion.

WELCOME TO UBUNTU WORLD !!

Comment: when i say to make it,i mean to perform the installation of ubuntu server in one of those 3 partitions

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As always when something is being done with files, you should backup any and all important things. If you do this and then just select the 3rd partition (does it have *any* data on it?) it should install there and then on boot-up give you the option to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

There is usually minimal risk to installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, but back up your data just to be safe. The 18GB of free space are plenty to install Ubuntu in, though depending on how it is used it may become full, so you might want to add some space to that partition from the 225GB one, but that would come later.

As for right now, you should be totally safe installing to the third partition using using the `Manual` option during the install. Just select the third partition and then go on from there.

Comment: also 18GB has no files in it,it's free space