# Can't Open Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS .iso file?

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS to my Windows 7 64-bit computer, but when I try to open and run the download, I receive the following message:  `Windows can't open this file`. How do I open and run this file?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step

Comment: Because you need to read http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server ... And basically, if you are asking this question, you probably need to look at Ubuntu desktop before. Ubuntu server instructions are terser because they're  thought for system administrator with experience in deployment of Unix system...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it doesn't quite work like that.

Ubuntu is an Operating System much like the windows you are running. The download is a bootable image which can't simply be 'run'. There are two main options:

1. Install it as a virtual operating system (using a program such as Virtual Box) which would allow you to run it inside your current Windows operating system.
2. Install it as a base operating system on the computer you intend to run it on this would have nothing to do with windows whatsoever (although there are ways of having them side by side on the same computer [known as a 'dual boot'] which would allow you to select whether you want to start Ubuntu or windows when you turn on your computer).

Method two would certainly give you the most out of your Ubuntu experience. For this you would have to burn the downloaded image to a CD using image burning software (not just writing the file to the disk conventionally). After burning this disk you would have to boot into it by changing your BIOS's boot order on start up. After that, it would be quite straight forward. There are plenty of forums and youtube videos that could help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have software for the ISO file, like daemon tools, you can install Wubi (14.04 supports it). Other ways are to boot from real DVD.(where the Ubuntu iso is burned) or VM.