# How to setup Ubuntu server web development environment

Tags: server, git, websites

Step by step instructions for setting up **Ubuntu server web development environment**   with `git`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask questions spanning multiple areas, you need to find one expert versed in all these areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions about the web server and the Git server respectively and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.