# Installing Ubuntu server 12.04 - usb is set as primary device

Tags: server, grub2, usb

I'm trying to install ubuntu server 12.04 from usb. In bios, I'm setting usb as first to boot and then follow steps from [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step).
But when it comes to installing GRUB, it recommends to install it on master boot record - and than it installs it on /dev/sda - which is this very same USB! Then I'm becoming some kind of error. So, I'm manually choosing to install it on /dev/sdb1 (which should be my disk), installation goes OK.
But after rebooting I'm becoming only blinking cursor.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Try `/dev/sdb`  which is a disk device. `/dev/sdb1` is the 1st partition.

Comment: I have unplugged the USB, so the first to boot was this disk. I will try with /dev/sdb. Thank you.