# Minimal OS for KVM

Tags: 15.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core

While there are minimal OS (CoreOS, Ubuntu Core etc) for container hypervisors, I would like to know if there is a minimal OS for KVM too. By a minimal OS for KVM I mean an OS which can be installed on a bare metal machine and has nothing more than what is required to run KVM and control it remotely. It seems people are trying to achieve this by installing ubuntu core on bare metal. However I could not find any concrete example on this.

If there is no minimal OS for KVM, what all things I can remove from ubuntu 15.04 to convert it to a minimal OS for KVM?

Answer (score 1):

I would install Ubuntu server edition and select only `virtual machine host` at the `Software Selection` step. See [also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step).

Comment: Well the confusion is that why one should use ubuntu server as OS hypervisor host and ubuntu core as container hypervisor host. Why not use ubuntu core for both types of hypervisor?

Comment: You don't have to use Ubuntu as the VM guest. With the minimal Ubuntu server installation, as per my answer, you would be all set to use KVM. Typically, I install more stuff on my Ubuntu servers, but KVM is all that I use for VMs.

Answer (score 0):

There is one now:

Minimal Ubuntu is a set of Ubuntu images designed for automated deployment at scale and made available across a range of cloud substrates. 
...
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal