# Install Ubuntu server on IBM x3200 m3 server (7328ac1)

Tags: server, ibm

The ibm x3200 m3 tower server (7328ac1) doesn't have any OS on it. I bought a new hard drive and want to know how to install Ubuntu server on it.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

You can burn the Ubuntu ISO on a USB and boot this USB up on your machine

You can burn iso's on a usb with tools like Rufus : https://rufus.akeo.ie

If that doesnt work i suggest to do it on the old way with an CD and burn the ISO on it with i a tool like http://www.imgburn.com

I hope this helps you!

if you have any question just ask them!