# How do I install Ubuntu server?

Tags: boot, server, grub2, usb

So I purchased a server recently, and I want to install Ubuntu server onto it, as I am following this guide, ([How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)), it's explaining to set the BIOS to boot into the USB stick. However, I do all that, but once I boot into it, the server shows an error saying that I haven't "installed a kernel", and it brings me to GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2, where if I type boot, it'll show ( Error: you need to load the kernel first. ) How do I fix this? I have a Intel SR1600URHS server. Also, I am using the Mac Linux USB Loader program on Mac to make my USB stick a bootable stick. Any help is appreciated, thanks!