# Ubuntu Server via LAN

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I was wondering if the following would be possible (and hopefully get some pointers on how to get this done).

I would like to install Ubuntu Server on an old computer and be able to connect to it and browse files by connecting a LAN cable from my new computer. If possible, I'd like to have it accept all connections over LAN and only accept connections over LAN.

That is, I want to have some influence over files and software on the old computer without having a keyboard or screen connected to it.

Is this possible (and how would you go about it)?

Comment: Great question!  I meant for the old computer to be offline and only communicate over LAN.

Comment: What will your new computer run?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.somehing

Comment: I'd suggest (assuming you have already backed up anything of value on the old computer), that you install ubuntu, selecting OpenSSH Server during the package selection screen, connect it to your network switch/router, then come back with more detailed questions after playing with your initial setup.  If you have a typical home setup with a NAT'ing router between you and the internet, the ubuntu machine will only be accessible from the LAN in the initial configuration, and OpenSSH will allow you to connect and browse, although possibly not in the way you'd find preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Install Ubuntu server in the old computer

Follow the instructions in [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)

Towards the end, at the `Software Selection` window:

[image]

Select `Openssh Server`, the first one in the image above. You will use `ssh` to connect to the server and interact with it. It will be a command line interface, as the server does not have any GUI.

## Connect the old computer to the new computer

I assume the new computer already has Ubuntu Desktop installed. The connection will be using a LAN cable. For simplicity, I assume it will be via a wired router. That is, both the computers are connected by LAN cables to a wired router.

## Find the Local IP address of the old computer

Log in to the old computer terminal and enter:

```
ifconfig
```

You will see something like

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55  
          inet addr:192.168.x.yyy  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Note down the `inet addr:`. the x may be eitehr 0 or 1, and yyy will be another number. It is the local LAN IP address of your server. You will need this to connect to the old computer.

You will also need the user ID and password of the server in the old computer. You created these when you installed the Ubuntu server in the old computer.

## Try to connect from the new computer

Open a terminal in the new computer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
ssh server_user_ID@192.168.x.yyy
```

Note: use your own server's user ID and the IP address you noted down above.

You will be prompted for password. Enter your server user's password. Nothing will be seen on the terminal and the cursor will not move. This is normal.

If successful, you will see the command prompt change from the new computer's `userID@NewComputer:~$` to `ServerUserID@oldcomputer:~$`.

If this step works, congratulations. You can control your old computer from the new computer.

## Copy and move files between computers with `Nautilus` in the New computer

Open Nautilus and find the Menu item "Connect to server".

[image]

Under Server Address Enter:

sftp://server_user_id@192.168.x.yyy/home/server_user_id

Press `Connect`. You will see a password dialog box:

[image]

Enter the password associated with server_user_id and select if you want the password is to be remembered or not. Again click Connect.

Now you should see your home folder of the laptop.

Notice there is a new entry under **Network** on the left panel of Nautilus that begins with server_user_id. Right click on it and choose "Add Bookmark" to create a permanent bookmark for your server's home folder in the Nautilus of the Desktop.

Now you can access the files and folders in your old computer from your new computer.

See the  **Ubuntu to Ubuntu** section of [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201) for more details.

## Advanced topics

- Use public and private key pairs to login and disable password based login. Private/public keys are more secure than passwords, as they are harder to guess. This is not an issue if you only access your server from within your home. The default settings of your router should prevent any attempts from reaching the server from outside. See [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)
- [Network File System (**NFS**)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html) can be used to attach the server folders to the desktop's system when the Desktop boots, assuming that the server is always running.

Thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for suggesting these topics in the comments.

Hope this helps

Comment: @V.Vocor also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login  for avoiding passwords in this setup. And checkout https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html if you want to keep it mounted all the time