# how to install ubuntu server over dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 16 :/ don't ask me why.

I want to install a Ubuntu server and delete completely the previous OS. how can I do this?

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned "delete completely the previous OS", but you mention 2 OS's. Do you want to remove them both or keep one? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, I meant both previous OS's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make installation media for installing Ubuntu Server.
2. Backup all the data that you want to save from Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 to another storage device.
3. Boot from the Ubuntu Server installation media, and install Ubuntu Server in the [usual way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step/340966#340966). In the *Partition Disks* screen of the Ubuntu Server installer, you can select one of the *Guided - use entire disk* partitioning methods.