# Dell Power Edge 860 - Ubuntu -18.04 LTS Install

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my dell power edge 860 rack server. The server does not currently have an OS... will I need one or can I simply pop in the burned dvd of the Ubuntu Server iso and load it from there?

Also, do I need to be plugged into ethernet the entire time or could I use WiFi?

Please help. I am a beginner.

Comment: Boot from the installation media and install. You don't need any internet connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it!