# Installation guide server in portuguese?

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, 32-bit, documentation

Quero instalar o Ubuntu server 18.04 em um PC antigo de arquitetura 32 Bits, gostaria de saber se há uma documentação em Português.
Grato

English translation:

> I want to install Ubuntu server 18.04 on an old PC with 32 Bit
> architecture, I wonder if there is documentation in Portuguese. Thank
> you.

Comment: [This](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=auto&tl=pt&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fosslinux.com%2F6406%2Fhow-to-install-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts.htm) may help. (Isto pode ajudar. AskUbuntu é um site de língua inglesa.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

During a point release of the 18.04 Ubuntu serverguide, multi-language publication was dropped. For several years the feedback had been that system administrators actually preferred English, even if it was not their native language. Also preparations were underway to switch away from the docbook markup utility to discourse for 20.04, which would only ever be English. Opinions were that the barrier of entry was simply too high for docbook and the Ubuntu Serverguide would benefit from more subject matter expert contributions (i.e. from the server team) with the simpler discourse.

Dropping multi-language publication early was partly as a test, to see if anyone complained. Nobody did.

The Portuguese version of the 18.04 Ubuntu serverguide only had about 16% of the strings translated anyhow. Only French, Russian, and Italian versions had a majority of strings translated.

Please also see:

https://translations.launchpad.net/serverguide

https://help.ubuntu.com/