# Downloading CLI version of Ubuntu

Tags: server, 20.04

Where can I download and install the CLI version of Ubuntu server? I installed one Ubuntu server but it was the GUI version. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. First of all, you can download either edition from exactly the same place and the Server edition comes without a desktop environment so if the one you installed has a "GUI" then it wasn't the Server edition.

Comment: Go to https://ubuntu.com/download/server and select **Option2 - Manual server installation**. Then click on the **Download Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS** green button. There is no GUI version of Ubuntu server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340965/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-step-by-step) and [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/)

Answer (score 2):

The best CLI/TUI version of Ubuntu server installer is netboot mini.iso.

You can get mini.iso of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

and then build any type of system on top of it using Aptitude and other CLI-based lightweight tools without huge massive Snaps and cloud init.