# How to remove the some applications I don't use from Xubuntu?

Tags: apt, 13.10, xubuntu, xfce

[image]

The apps that have red dots next to them, I want to uninstall, since I have synapse, kazam, xpad instead and the rest, I don't need. I tried Software Center, and synaptic and `apt-get`, and could not locate them.

Also how to remove xfce4-terminal? I tried `apt-get`, but it will remove a billion library related to xfce, is it safe to remove it that way? Because I have terminator and xterm.

I want to remove the **Electronic** section, because it only has Arduino IDE, which is also available in the development section, thus I don't need it.

Comment: The answers below will help you. As an alternate, in my experience, ubuntu is not the best distro to start striping down. There tend to be more dependencies per package (part of what makes ubuntu so easy). With modern computers, what do you gain by removing things ? If you want to use Ubuntu, and do a minimal install, use the minimal iso - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD then build up, installing only what you need (xfce rather then xubuntu-desktop). Alternately switch to Arch or Gentoo. FWIW, gentoo is not enough faster to offset the time compiling, YMMV.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/321924/how-do-i-configure-a-minimal-desktop-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script to find the package names:

```bash
programs_to_rm=('Application Finder' 'Notes' 'Onboard' 'Orage Globaltime' 'Screenshot')

results=()
for prog in "${programs_to_rm[@]}"; do
    result="$(grep -lR -m1 "^Name=$prog$" /usr/share/applications | tail -n1)"
    result="$(dpkg -S "$result" | head -n1)"
    results+=("${result%%: *}")
done

echo "${results[@]}"
```

Basically, this should work:

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-appfinder xfce4-notes onboard orage xfce4-screenshooter
```

---

To remove the Electronics section:

1. Command:

   ```
   sudo -H nano "$(grep -lRm1 'Arduino IDE' /usr/share/applications)"
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, then type `Categories=`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Edit the line to remove `Electronics;`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove them from the Menu, [Alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/), or 'Main Menu' should work.

[image: alacarte]

Answer (score 0):

It's best NOT to remove any software that "comes with" Xubuntu unless you have very little room on your hard drive.  A few are safe to remove (like Abiword and Gnumeric if you prefer LibreOffice), but so much software is dependent on other stuff it can create new problems.  It's not using anything but storage space if it's "just there."

Comment: If we ever do get the xubuntu-core bit working, there will be a basic core that people can build upon with their own app mixes perhaps.  It is coming but we're not there yet.  Depending upon what Unit193 comes up with and if I get time away from My Day Job, we might see it in 14.10 potentially.