# 18.04 Gnome screen vertical bar

Tags: 18.04, screen, resize

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome. I did something that changed my screen. Now I have a vertical black bar under the Settings icon.

Restart and reboot didn't change it.

Settings->Displays->Resolutions doesn't fix it.

What do I need to do?

[image: Snapshot]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome... that's Mate, not gnome.

Comment: It looks like you've added an extra (empty) panel to the right edge of your desktop. You should try to remove the panel.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. If it had been a snake.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/118953/how-to-delete-a-panel-in-the-classic-desktop